# Inner table adds 1-2 pixels of padding on the left

Tags: html, css, html-table

Let's say I have a table:

```
 <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            Hello How are you this is a TEST!
         </td>
      <tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <table>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                         Hello this a test 2!
                     </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          <td>
      <tr>
 </table>
```

Just as an example, I have one TD in my main table, however I need to do 3 TD in my child table. If i do it as I shown above, it looks like this.

```
 Hello How are you this is a TEST!
  Hello this is a Test2!
```

The inner table gives me a padding-left of about 1-2 pixels. Is there any way to line up both statements?

Comment: May I ask why did you choose this layout? Is it a real representation of a table of you're stuck in the 90s and using table to handle the alignment of elements in the page? :)

Comment: @AlonEitan you certain may ask. I'm creating some Asp Web Forms, that ask for medical information. Working with tables seems to be the best since I have many different input I require user to input.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you may benefit from working with a grid system like [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/) because table should be used for **actual** tables and not for aligning elements on page. But of course you should do whatever suits you

Comment: @AlonEitan I'd love to use Bootstrap as well. Except some of the devs here are old school and they prefer to stick to tables! Oh well. Only vanilla JS, not other libraries kind of guys! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collapse your borders and remove your cell padding. Also you have a few td and tr tags improperly closed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            Hello How are you this is a TEST!
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
              <table>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                         Hello this a test 2!
                     </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. That space is due to two factors:

1. Table cells, by default, have space *between* them. To collapse cells together, you need to apply `border-collapse: collapse` to the parent table.
2. Table cells have 1px of `padding` by default. You'll need to get rid of that by doing `td { padding: 0; }`

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Hello How are you this is a TEST!
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Hello this a test 2!
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you'd like a more visual example, you can check out [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tsje9sc/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<style>
  table {
    border-spacing:0;

    }
  td {
    margin-left:0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }  
</style>
```

...

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            Hello How are you this is a TEST!
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            Hello this a test 2!
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```